# TinyMCE - TypeError: r is undefined

Tags: jquery, tinymce

With the latest pgrade of wordpress tinyMCE was upgraded. This resulted in my custom plugin being rendered useless with deprecated calls. I was able correctly format the event handling and now I am seeing the issue:

```
TypeError: r is undefined
```

Can anyone explain what 'r' is? Any way to further debug tinyMCE?

```
(function($) {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.editor_toolkit', {
    init : function(ed, url) {
                var VK = {
                    DELETE: 46, BACKSPACE: 8, ENTER: 13, TAB: 9, SPACEBAR: 32, UP: 38, DOWN: 40, LEFT: 37, RIGHT: 39,
                    modifierPressed: function (e) {
                        return e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey;
                    }
                };

            function scrollToThisNode(node, padding) {
                vp = ed.dom.getViewPort( ed.getWin() )
                y = ed.dom.getPos(node).y;
                if (y < vp.y || y + padding > vp.y + vp.h) {
                    ed.getWin().scrollTo(0, y < vp.y ? y : y - vp.h + padding);
                }
            }

        // Adds an observer to the onInit event using tinyMCE.init
        tinyMCE.init({
           setup : function(ed) {
              ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
                  console.debug('Editor is done: ' + ed.id);
                  ed.dom.addClass(ed.getBody(), 'editor-toolkit');

                    // Last-ditch effort to structure content
                    $('#post').submit(function(){
                        $( ed.getBody() ).children('p').each(function(){
                            $(this).replaceWith('<div><p>' + $(this).html() + '</p></div>');
                        });
                        return true;
                    });
              });
           }
           plugins: "compat3x"

        });

        ed.on('BeforeSetcontent', function(ed, o){
          if (adminpage == 'post-new-php' && !$( ed.getBody() ).hasClass('editor-toolkit-init') ) {
                o.content = '<div><p><br /></p>';
                ed.dom.addClass(ed.getBody(), 'editor-toolkit-init');
            }
        });

        ed.on('KeyDown', function(ed, event){
          if ( event.keyCode === VK.DELETE && !VK.modifierPressed(event) ) {

          }
          if ( event.keyCode === VK.BACKSPACE && !VK.modifierPressed(event) ) {

          }
          if ( event.keyCode === VK.ENTER && !VK.modifierPressed(event) ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var currentNode = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getRng().startContainer, ed.dom.isBlock);
                var prevSibling = $(currentNode).length > 0 ? currentNode.previousSibling : false;
                var nextSibling = $(currentNode).length > 0 ? currentNode.nextSibling : false;
                var prevPrevSibling = $(prevSibling).length > 0 ? prevSibling.previousSibling : false;
                var nodeIndex = $(currentNode).length > 0 ? $(currentNode).index() : false;
                var nodeIsLast = $(currentNode).length > 0 ? $(currentNode).is(':last-child') : null;

                var nodeParent = ed.dom.getParent(currentNode, 'div');
                var nodeParentPrevSibling = $(nodeParent).length > 0 ? nodeParent.previousSibling : false;
                var nodeParentNextSibling = $(nodeParent).length > 0 ? nodeParent.nextSibling : false;
                var nodeParentChildren = $(nodeParent).length > 0 ? $(nodeParent).children().length : false;

                var contentBody = ed.getBody();
                var contentFirstChild = ed.getBody().firstChild;

                var newNodeData = '<p><br /></p>';

                function isEmpty(node) {
                    if (ed.dom.isEmpty(node) || node.firstChild.nodeName === 'BR' || $(node).html() === '&nbsp;')
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;

                }

                switch(true) {
                    // Start new block at selection point ("after")
                    case nodeIsLast && nodeIndex + 1 === nodeParentChildren && nodeParentChildren > 3:
                    case nodeIndex === 2 && nodeParentChildren === 3 && ( !isEmpty(prevSibling) || !isEmpty(prevPrevSibling) ):
                        if ( isEmpty(prevSibling) && isEmpty(currentNode) ) {
                            $(nodeParent).after('<div>' + newNodeData + '</div>');
                            ed.dom.remove(prevSibling);
                            ed.dom.remove(currentNode);
                            newBlock = nodeParent.nextSibling;
                            ed.execCommand('mceSelectNode', false, newBlock.firstChild.firstChild);
                            ed.selection.select(newBlock.firstChild.firstChild, true);  // Extra to get FF to show cursor
                            scrollToThisNode(newBlock, 100);
                        }
                        break;
                    // Start new block at selection point ("before")
                    case nodeIndex === 2:
                        if ( isEmpty(prevSibling) && isEmpty(prevPrevSibling) ) {
                            $(nodeParent).before('<div>' + newNodeData + '</div>');
                            ed.dom.remove(prevSibling);
                            ed.dom.remove(prevPrevSibling);
                            newBlock = nodeParent.previousSibling;
                            if ( $(newBlock).is(':first-child') ) {
                                ed.execCommand('mceSelectNode', false, newBlock.firstChild.firstChild);
                                ed.selection.select(newBlock.firstChild.firstChild, true);  // Extra to get FF to show cursor
                                scrollToThisNode(newBlock, 100);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    // Correct new paragraph created outside a block
                    case currentNode && currentNode.nodeName === 'P' && !nodeParent:
                        newNodeData = $(currentNode).html();
                        $(currentNode).after('<div><p>' + newNodeData + '</p></div>');
                        newBlock = currentNode.nextSibling;
                        ed.dom.remove(currentNode);
                        break;
                    // Rare but best to cover all angles (problematic on empty pages)
                    case contentFirstChild.nodeName === 'P':
                        $(contentFirstChild).replaceWith('<div>' + newNodeData + '</div>');
                        newBlock = ed.getBody().firstChild;
                        ed.execCommand('mceSelectNode', false, newBlock.firstChild.firstChild);
                        ed.selection.select(newBlock.firstChild.firstChild, true);  // Extra to get FF to show cursor
                        break;
                    // Fix empty block
                    case ed.dom.is(ed.selection.getNode(), 'div') && isEmpty(currentNode):
                        ed.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, '<p></p>');
                        break;
                }

                // Run a check for paragraphs outside a block, at root level
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(contentBody).children('p').each(function(){
                        $(this).replaceWith('<div><p>' + $(this).html() + '</p></div>');
                    });
                }, 250);

                ed.execCommand('mceCleanup');
            }, 0);
          }
        });

  },
  createControl : function(n, cm) {
      return null;
  },
  getInfo : function() {
      return {
          longname : "Editor Toolkit",
          author : 'Studio Anino',
          authorurl : 'http://studioanino.com/',
          infourl : 'http://studioanino.com/',
          version : "1.0"
      };
  }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add('editor_toolkit', tinymce.plugins.editor_toolkit);
})(jQuery);
```

**Is it at all possible to downgrade tinyMCE within wordpress?**

Comment: Short of downgrading WordPress, no, you can't downgrade tinyMCE without significant effort and modification to WP Core. Do you have any more details such as the full error message with line number and file, and the code for your broken tinyMCE plugin?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to provide as much as I can (very little :/). The problem is indicated within wp-tinymce.php (line 9, col 21717). This should actually go to the source: wp-includes/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js. I have pasted the plugin code here, I have commented out the deprecated calls: http://pastebin.com/kT8R3S9L

Comment: If it's any help, I did find the plugin on github: https://github.com/studioanino/editor-toolkit

Comment: Rather than using a pastebin, please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/157979/edit) to include the relevant code.